# docker-compose.yml set argument when building Dockerfile from file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like to somehow get the contents of my `.key` file set as an argument for the docker compose build (NOTICE that there are spaces, these must be kept!).

`.key`:

```
165 756 873
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
         KEY: ${cat .key}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables inside your docker-compose.yml

so if you run:

```
key='165 756 873' docker-compose build
```

you can set the key value inside your docker-compose.yml like:

```
KEY: $key
```